# Count of Table1_IDs in Table2_arrays

Tags: sql, presto

I'm working with two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
id int,
name varchar
)

CREATE TABLE Table2
(
id int,
name varchar,
link array<int>
)
```

**Table2.link** contains values that correspond to **Table1.id**. I'd like to count how many times each **Table1.id** appears in an instance of  **Table2.link**. This would be trivial using cell references in Excel, but I can't figure out how to do it with a SQL query.

Comment: What does "array" mean?  That is not a native SQL data type.

Comment: @luke.samuel.mccarthy I suggest to put here some more detailed description of tables, or DDL that could describe how tables look like. It will help to understand the problem.

Comment: Can you please post some sample for both tables

Comment: Any answer will be database specific. What database are you using?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I'm using Presto. Based on your answer, it looks like 'unnest' is what I need, although the implementation will involve a cross join in Presto.

Comment: Arrays are part of the SQL standard. See *ISO/IEC 9075-2:2011 4.10.2 Arrays* as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presto

```
select    *
from     (select    l.id           
                   ,count(*)    as cnt
          from      Table2 cross join unnest (link) as l(id)
          group by  l.id     
          ) t2
where     t2.id in (select id from Table1)
order by  id
```

---

```
presto:default> select    *
             -> from     (select    l.id
             ->                    ,count(*)    as cnt
             ->           from      Table2 cross join unnest (link) as l(id)
             ->           group by  l.id
             ->           ) t2
             -> where     t2.id in (select id from Table1)
             -> order by  id;
 id | cnt
----+-----
  1 |   7
  2 |   5
  3 |   4
(3 rows)
```

PostgreSQL demo

```
create table Table1 (id int);
create table Table2 (arr int[]);

insert into Table1 values 
    (1),(2),(3)
;

insert into Table2 values 
    (array[1,5]),(array[1,3]),(array[1,2,3]),(array[2,3])
   ,(array[1,2,4]),(array[1,2]),(array[1,3,5]),(array[1,2,4])
;
```

---

```
select    *
from     (select    unnest(arr) as id             
                   ,count(*)    as cnt
          from      Table2
          group by  id     
          ) t2
where     t2.id in (select id from Table1)
order by  id
```

---

```
+----+-----+
| id | cnt |
+----+-----+
| 1  | 7   |
+----+-----+
| 2  | 5   |
+----+-----+
| 3  | 4   |
+----+-----+
```

Comment: Please check the Presto version

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot, really appreciate the help